# Regex to accept numbers with spaces

Tags: regex

We have a expression to accept regex with spaces but the pattern should match below examples

```
ABC1234   
TAC4 566    
T A C 4 5 6 6    
KA C4 56 6
```

Basically all spaces should be accepted with 3 alpha characters[A-z] and followed by 4 numbers[0-9]

I tried using this regex but it doesnt work :

```
^((\s)*([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{4}))?$
```

Comment: Please do add your tried code/regex in your question, thank you.

Comment: I tried this @RavinderSingh13: ^((\s)*([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{2}))?$ but it fails

Comment: Maybe removing all spaces beforehand and then test for `^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}$` is an option? That would at least simplify the regex quite a bit

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no trailing/leading psaces (as per given sample data), the very verbose version could be:

```
^[A-Z](?: ?[A-Z]){2} ?\d(?: ?\d){3}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/si9Npv/1). It basically means the same as `^[A-Z] ?[A-Z] ?[A-Z] ?\d ?\d ?\d ?\d$` where:

- `^` - Match start-line anchor;
- `[A-Z]` - An uppercase alpha;
- `(?: ?[A-Z]){2}` - Non-capture group to match an optional space and an uppercase alpha twice;
- `?\d` - Optional space and single digit;
- `(?: ?\d){3}` - Non-capture group to match an optional space and a digit three times;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: I tried this with this expression but it showing me incorrect result : A B 1 23

Comment: @NoelSimon because that string does not follow the rules you have layed out in the question. Only two alpha chars present.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\s*` after the pattern for letter or number to allow any amount of spaces after that character. Put these in groups so you can then quantify them to allow 3 letters followed by 4 numbers.

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]\s*){3}(\d\s*){4}$
```

Comment: Will this work if there are spaces in between the characters eg: A B C 1 2 3 4

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `\s*` after each character.

Answer (score 1):

`/[A-Za-z]\s?[A-Za-z]\s?[A-Za-z]\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d/g` it's big and inelegant but it'll meet your criteria.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x0STtG/2)